# Log scale using Bokeh's scatter function

Tags: python, bokeh

How do I get log scales when using Bokeh's `scatter` function.  I'm looking for something like the following:

```
scatter(x, y, source=my_source, ylog=True)
```

or

```
scatter(x, y, source=my_source, yscale='log')
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Something along these lines will work:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import *

N = 100

x = np.linspace(0.1, 5, N)

output_file("logscatter.html", title="log axis scatter example")

figure(tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,previewsave",
       y_axis_type="log", y_range=[0.1, 10**2], title="log axis scatter example")

scatter(x, np.sqrt(x), line_width=2, line_color="yellow", legend="y=sqrt(x)")

show()
```

Alternative you can also pass the "log"-related parameters in the scatter call instead of figure (but I recommend you to write it as I showed above):

```
scatter(x, np.sqrt(x), y_axis_type="log", y_range=[0.1, 10**2], line_width=2, line_color="yellow", legend="y=sqrt(x)")
```

Hope it helps! ;-)