# Bokeh histogram with logarithmic y axis

Tags: python, bokeh

To create a histogram in Bokeh I can use:

```
p = Histogram(results, yscale="linear", bins=50, title = 'hist plot')
show(p)
```

But the options for yscale are only 'linear', 'categorical', 'datetime'

Any idea on how to create a histogram with a logarithmic yscale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `Histogram` doesn't allow this, but you can try this low-level approach (based in part on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25025224/3025981) to similar question and [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/histogram.html) from the docs).

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

p = figure(tools="pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,previewsave",
       y_axis_type="log", y_range=[10**(-4), 10**0], title="log histogram")

hist, edges = np.histogram(df['mpg'], density=True, bins=50)
p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:],
       fill_color="#036564", line_color="#033649")
```

[image: image generated]

Comment: In Bokeh 2.4.2, nothing was plotting with the suggested script. To make it work, I changed "bottom=0" by "bottom=0.00001".